# Resetting Variable : Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to reset the variable foundAlphaNum back to 0 when I read a new line feed, but when I do foundalphanum = 0 it gives me a segmentation fault. How would I fix this?

Within the function:

```
  void removechar ( char *stringInput, size_t length)
```

.

```
  unsigned int i = 0;
  char *currentChar = stringInput;
  char modifiedString[length];
  int foundAlphaNum = 0;

  while ((currentChar != '\0') && (i < (length - 1)))
  {

      if (isalnum(*currentChar))
      {
          foundAlphaNum = 1;
      }

      if (*currentChar != ' ' && *currentChar != '\t' && *currentChar !='\n' && foundAlphaNum)
      {
          modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
          i++;
      }
      else if ((*currentChar == ' ' || *currentChar == '\t') && !foundAlphaNum)
      {
          modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
          i++;
      }
      else if(*currentChar == '\n')
       {
         modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
         i++;
         foundAlphaNum = 0;
       }

     currentChar++;

 }

 // add null terminating char (maybe...)
 modifiedString[i] = '\0';
 printf("%s\n", modifiedString);
```

Comment: `foundalphanum = 0` very unlikely, note that there might be undefined behavior in your program, you don't know what to expect, but the assignment will not cause the segmentation fault... please post the rest of the code? where is `modifiedString` declared, is it a parameter, show the code where you declare it, also `currentChar`.

Comment: `(currentChar != '\0')` is wrong. That should simply be `(*currentChar)` or `(*currentChar != '\0')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
while ((currentChar != '\0') && (i < (length - 1)))
```

is wrong. `currentChar` is a pointer into your buffer. It should not be NULL *ever*, therefore making your first test meaningless.

It should read:

```
while (*currentChar && (i < (length - 1)))
```

which will eval as `false` when `currentChar` lands on the terminator of your string, or `i` surpasses `length`-less-one.

Note: I've done no diligence debugging the *rest* of your code, but that is clearly bad. Worth noting both `stringInput` and `length` should be validated prior to entering this loop. Believe me you don't want to be walking `length-1` when `length` is `size_t` zero, nor do you want to be dereferencing a `NULL` pointer on inception.

Best of luck